# Eval Slash Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, eval

I'm trying to create an eval command using slash command but this command keep showing the error. I believe there's a v12 code that I use in it.

> sorry if my code are mess up. Still new in discord.js.

Here's my code

```
const Discord = module.require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "eval",
  description: "Execute a JavaScript Code (owmer only)",
  options: [
      {
          name: "code",
          description: "The question you want to ask the magic 8ball",
          type: 'STRING',
      }
  ],
  run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
            function clean(text) {
            if (typeof text === "string")
                return text
                    .replace(/`/g, "`" + String.fromCharCode(8203))
                    .replace(/@/g, "@" + String.fromCharCode(8203));
            else return text;
        }
        let owner = '833843608905842700'

        if (!owner.includes(interaction.author.id)) return;

        try {
            const code = args.join(" ");
            let evaled = eval(code);

            if (typeof evaled !== "string") evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);

            message.react("✅");
            var emb = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Result')
                .setDescription(`\`\`\`js` + '\n' + clean(evaled) + `\n` + `\`\`\``)
                .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setColor(0xd26a0e)
            message.channel.send(emb);
        } catch (err) {
            message.react("⚠");
            var emb = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Result')
                .setDescription(`\`\`\`js` + '\n' + clean(err) + `\n` + `\`\`\``)
                .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setColor(0xd26a0e)
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [emb] })

        }
  }};
```

Comment: You should never ever pass user input to `eval`! That's a major security issue. It's best to avoid eval all together.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hi here's your eval command code for discord.js v13 slash command.

```
    const {
    MessageEmbed
    } = require("discord.js");
    const {
    inspect
    } = require("util");

    module.exports = {
        name: "eval",
        description: "owner's only",
        options: [{
            name: "code",
            description: "type a code to execute",
            type: 3,
            required: true
    }],
    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
        const nembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("EVAL").setColor("RANDOM")
            .setDescription("❌ You dont have perms to use this command. Only Owner's can use this command")
            .setThumbnail(interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setFooter(interaction.member.user.tag)

        if (!client.config.owner.includes(interaction.member.user.id)) return interaction.followUp({
            embeds: [nembed]
        });

        let toEval = interaction.options.getString("code")


        try {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("EVAL").setColor("RANDOM")
                .setDescription("❌ Error: `Cannot evaluate nothing`")
                .setThumbnail(interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setFooter(interaction.member.user.tag)
            let evaluated = inspect(eval(toEval, {
                depth: 0
            }))
            if (!toEval) return interaction.followUp({
                embeds: [embed]
            });
            const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("EVAL").setColor("RANDOM")
                .setDescription("❌ Error: `Request is too long.`")
                .setThumbnail(interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setFooter(interaction.member.user.tag)

            if (evaluated.length > 1950) return interaction.followUp({
                embeds: [embed1]
            });
            let hrDiff = process.hrtime(process.hrtime());
            const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("EVAL").setColor("RANDOM")
                .setDescription(`Executed in ${hrDiff[0] > 0 ? `${hrDiff[0]}s` : ''}${hrDiff[1] / 1000000}ms.*\`\`\`javascript\n${evaluated}\n\`\`\``)
                .setThumbnail(interaction.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setFooter(interaction.member.user.tag)
            interaction.followUp({
                embeds: [embed2]
            })
        } catch (e) {
            interaction.followUp({
                content: `An error occurred : \`${e.message}\``
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).